How to calculate the center of mass of a irregular polygon in Godot?
Or to calculate the centroid of a 2D polygon assuming uniform mass density, which is my case. The polygon can be either concave or convex.

Does this refer only to convex polygons or potentially to concave ones as well? If concave support is needed, you will first need a step to break down that concave polygon into multiple convex polygons, then calculate their centroids, then average these centroids to get the final centroid position of the entire concave polygon.

updated the question, it needs to be a function for both cases

For that, you need 2 functions, one to calculate the area of a polygon, in this case by using Gauss' shoelace formula and another to calculate the centroid / geometric center
func calculate_area(mesh_vertices: PackedVector2Array) -> float:
    var result := 0.0
    var num_vertices := mesh_vertices.size()
    
    for q in range(num_vertices):
        var p = (q - 1 + num_vertices) % num_vertices
        result += mesh_vertices[q].cross(mesh_vertices[p])
    
    return result * 0.5

func calculate_centroid(mesh_vertices: PackedVector2Array) -> Vector2:
    var centroid = Vector2()
    var area = calculate_area(mesh_vertices)
    var num_vertices = mesh_vertices.size()
    var factor = 0.0

    for q in range(num_vertices):
        var p = (q - 1 + num_vertices) % num_vertices
        factor = mesh_vertices[q].cross(mesh_vertices[p])
        centroid += (mesh_vertices[q] + mesh_vertices[p]) * factor

    centroid /= (6.0 * area)
    return centroid.abs()

